# Class design for two objects that derive from the same class but share no common methods

Tags: c++, oop

I have a set of classes that represent the storage of a font format in a file. Each font defines a set of Glyphs (A shape that maps to a UTF32 code).

Glyphs can be represented by an outline (A set of bezier curves in my case) or a bitmap.

My first thought was that this would lead to GlyphOutline and GlyphBitmap classes which would inherit from Glyph.

The only problem with this design is that there are no common methods. In order to do anything useful with either class i would need to use rtti (which i would prefer to avoid).

My question is: Can you think of a better way to represent a glyph / is there some design pattern that deals with this situation?

I have tried to make this language agnostic, but i am writing in c++ if it makes any difference.

EDIT:

I have considered using generics, where Glyph contains a referance to some/many GlyphRepresentations where T would be Outline or Bitmap or whatever else you could use to represent a glyph. I actually quite like this as a solution, as it solves the problem of a glyph represented by both a Outline and a Bitmap. However it would force the use of rtti.

This is probably the solution i would chose if i was using c# where reflection is wonderful and nice, but in the c++ environment i am working in rtti is implemented as a set of very complex macros, which i'm sure you can understand i am quite keen to avoid

EDIT:

In answer to oli, I agree with you to a point, but the isa relationship (as in GlyphOutline is a Glyph, and can do everything that a glyph can do) is there, which i believe implies that there should be inheritance? I am not sure about this, it seems there are good arguments either way.

My preferred solution so far is the visitor pattern, but that is just a comment not an answer atm, and i would like to wait a little longer to see if any other solutions surface.

Comment: can you not template on it, with no inheritance? And for the cases where you'd be tempted to use RTTI why can't those be virtual member functions?

Comment: It would help if we knew more about how `Glyph` instances are used. You are not doing polymorphism, which is... strange.

Comment: If you have no common behaviour, then it probably doesn't make sense to derive from a common base class.

Comment: Check out visitor pattern. It may be way to avoid rtti.

Comment: You should definitely have an interface, say IGlyph which will be implemented by both classes. IGlyph will provide methods to treat an object as a set of bezier curves. You may use a pure abstract base class for that purpose.

Comment: If I had IGlyph it could define methods GetCurves and GetBitmap, but this would imply methods HasCurves and HasBitmap. This i believe defeats the purpose of an abstract base class.

Comment: The Visitor pattern would just be moving that icky interface away from the design of glyph, which is preferable, but then i would prefer not to have to implement an interface like that at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as if methods such as `drawOnScreen()`, `getMetrics()`, `getCodePoint()` would be good candidates for polymorphic behaviour.

Comment: I agree, but this does not really solve the problem of distinguishing between a bitmap glyph and an outline glyph.

Comment: Going back through my asked questions, and being a little less bad at writing code, I now think that this answer should have got me thinking on the right track. I just didn't understand what you were driving at at the time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, if I understand you correctly, you may make a use of Builder design pattern as follows:

One may define a set of Glyphs. Each Glyph will implement the IGlyph interface which will allow an instance of the Font class to access sets of bezier curves.

```
class OutlineGlyph : public IGlyph
class BitmapGlyph : public IGlyph
```

Then one instantiates some of them and setup each of them via their concrete interfaces.

```
OutlineGlyph og;
og.Method(...)
```

Then one should instantiate FontBuilder class.

```
FontBuilder fontBuilder;
fontBuilder.AddGlyph(og);
fontBuilder.AddGlyph(bg);

Font* font = fontBuilder.CompileFont()
```

Comment: BitmapGlyph provides sets of beizer curves? Your answer implies that it does. Correct me if i have misunderstood.

Comment: I'm sorry, first time I've read your post I didn't notice BitmapGlyph and OutlineGlyph have different representation. Anyway IGlyph then will include methods common for both BitmapGlyph and OutlineGlyph. For example drawing code etc

Comment: The main point here, is that one may avoid the usage of rtti and visitor pattern just by distinguishing the work with concrete objects in a separate workflow stage

Comment: I cannot see how this avoids the use of either. How would i now get a bitmap representation of UTF32 code 123 from the font pointer in your example? As i understand your code i would receive an IGlyph*, which i cannot be sure contains a bitmap without some form of rtti.

Comment: It is important to state the list of responsibilities for the Font class. Maybe it would be better to have an interface IFont. Then you can create a class BitmapFont which implements IFont and provides a functionality to get a bitmap associated with it.

Comment: We considered this. The problem now exists in exactly the same way at a higher level. In addition in some fonts some glyphs are represented by bitmaps, and some by outlines. It would be nice (but not essential) to be able to deal with such fonts, which this model would not be able to do at all.

Comment: Well, I don't insist, but maybe it is worth to reconsider the architecture of the higher level. At any point in your design it is important to put all the code which depends on the nature of the font object in a correspondent concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

I vote for Templates and Interfaces!! Cant use inheritance because there is no common behavior. And i dont really understand why you should avoid RTTI its one of the better features of the language. If your current design pattern with RTTI solves the problem why change?

Comment: Using RTTI in place of polymorphism on virtual member function is just  A Bad Idea (c)

Comment: cause having code littered by if( dynamic_cast<Foo*>(p) ) else ... is far far more maintenable and easy to read that this->some_virtual_method(). It likes people abusing instanceof in JAVA, this means they dont understand the concept of virtual overload at all.

Comment: Sorry, but the wording of your comment is confusing. Do you mean far far **less** maintainable? I would much rather see:
 this->some_virtual_method() 
than: 
 if( dynamic_cast<Foo*>(p) ) else

Comment: I guess I should s/more/less sorry. Of course it's LESS manageable than the virtual call